# Computing integral with variable bounds in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Consider the following MWE in MATLAB:

```
f = @(t) integral(@(x) x.^2,0,t);
integral(f,0,1);
```

This yields the error

```
Error using integral (line 85) A and B must be floating-point scalars.
```

(and a bit more). How do I fix this? Is this even possible? I think the problem is the variable upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [**`integral`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) then set `'ArrayValued'` to `true` otherwise `t` would be an invalid end point in `integral(@(x) x.^2,0,t)`. So it would be:

```
f = @(t) integral(@(x) x.^2,0,t);
integral(f,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)

% ans =
%     0.0833
```

---

Alternately, since you're doing double integration, so use the function dedicated for this purpose i.e. [**`integral2`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html). For your example, it would be:

```
f = @(t,x) x.^2 ;
integral2(f,0,1,0, @(t) t)

% ans =
%     0.0833
```

---

If you have *Symbolic Math Toolbox*, you can also use [**`int`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) as `int(expr,var,a,b)` but it would be slower. For your case, it would be:

```
syms x t;
f = x.^2;
req = int(int(f,x,0,t),t,0,1);    % It gives 1/12
req = double(req);                % Convert to double if required
```